# setTimeout function doesnt stop execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stumbled upon a problem with setTimeout.

```
$current.removeClass(class2);
setTimeout(function(){$current.css('display', 'none')},1000);
if(!$current.is('#' + id)){
    $('#' + id).css('display','block');
    setTimeout(function(){$('#' + id).addClass(class2)}, 1000);
    $current = $('#' + id);
}
```

I want the if statement to be executed AFTER I add the css "display:none". How can I achieve this? I thought setTimeout would stop the execution of the code and then continue after the function has run.

Comment: Put all the stuff you want to execute after the `timeout` *in the callback*. Javascript doesn't have the equivalent of a `Sleep(1000)` function.

Comment: `setTimeout` *does not* stop the execution of code. That's the whole point of `setTimeout` - it's asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but I thought setTimeout doesn't have a callback?

Comment: @FrederikWitte: What did you think that function you are passing to `setTimeout` was? It's a callback.

Comment: Oh, then I didn't quite inform me of the terms. I thought u mean something like setTimeout(function(),delay,callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put that code inside the function within the timeout (code spacing is important as well...):

```
$current.removeClass(class2);
setTimeout(function() {
    $current.css('display', 'none')

    if( !$current.is('#' + id) ) {
        $('#' + id).css('display','block');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#' + id).addClass(class2)
        }, 1000);
        $current = $('#' + id);
    }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` will run the function after n milliseconds, but the rest of the script will continue to run.

If you want the rest of the code to not run until after the `display:none` you will need to move it into the function as well:

```js
$current.removeClass(class2);
setTimeout(function(){
  $current.css('display', 'none');

  if(!$current.is('#' + id)){
    $('#' + id).css('display','block');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#' + id).addClass(class2);
    }, 1000);
    $current = $('#' + id);
  }
},1000);
```